# Как сохранить векторную графику в файл на C#?

Tags: c#, графика

Рисую фигуры на поверхности формы в своем простеньком редакторе. 
Вопрос в том, как сохранить все нарисованное в файл векторного представления, чтобы фигуры могли редактироваться в других редакторах?
И, конечно, не помешала бы помощь с загрузкой векторных изображений в свой редактор.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69799/discussion-on-question-by-vanya-belyaev---c).

Answer (score 1):

- Как сохранить все нарисованное в файл векторного представления. Метод [msdn Save](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_IO_Stream_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_)

  ```
   // вначале создать пустой метафайл на диске или в памяти
   Metafile mf = new Metafile("tempfile.wmf", hdc);
   // Потом наполнить файл действиями
   //.... MetaGraphics.DrawRectangle
   // Потом сохранить
   mf.Save("1.wmf", ImageFormat.Wmf );
  ```
- Как загрузить [msdn MetaFile](http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.metafile.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Imaging_Metafile__ctor_System_String_)

  ```
  Metafile mf = new Metafile("1.wmf", hdc);
  ```
- Как редактировать в внешних редакторах... попробуйте извесные векторные редакторы такие как Corel, AutoCad.

Comment: совершенно не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил следующим образом: разобрался в теории, реализовал при помощи простого самодельного XML-файла. В нем храню данные об SVG-изображениях.

Comment: У вас в вопросе метафайл, про SVG хотя это и самый популярный формат - в вопросе, ни слова. То что проблему вы решили - это хорошо. Цель форума, есть рабочий вопрос - есть рабочий ответ. Ваш ответ - не является решением.